# "Document path cannot be empty." trying to connect to Firebase using Swiftui

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I was able to connect to my Firebase database for over a month now. the last couple of days, I've noticed performance issues, so I started exploring storing data on cache. I've used Database.database().isPersistenceEnabled = true, which improved performance tremendously. Later, I realized that when I update the data, the app doesn't sync with the database, so I've added

```
Database.database().reference(withPath: "Match").keepSynced(true)
```

I tried to delete a collection completely from Firebase, but my app was still showing cached data... a day later I gave up and recreate it the collection, then the app couldn't find it this time, as if it still remembers that I deleted it in the past..long story short, I've got rid of isPersistenceEnabled= true, along with keepSynced(true) just to get my app sync with firebase, and Now I'm not even able to load user collection. The original issue I had was with a .Match, and I was able to load user's profile etc. Wha's going on here? did I load he connection to Firebase? but how was I able to sign in? I have the User and Match collections in Firebase...
This is my code, and it fails in getDocuments

```
func downloadCurrentUserFromFirebase(userId: String, email: String) {
    
    FirebaseReference(.User).document(userId).getDocument { (snapshot, error) in << Code fails here
        
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
        
        if snapshot.exists {
            
            let user = FUser(_dictionary: snapshot.data() as! NSDictionary)
            user.saveUserLocally()
            
            user.getUserAvatarFromFirestore { (didSet) in
                
            }
            
        } else {
            //first login
            
            if let user = userDefaults.object(forKey: kCURRENTUSER) {
                FUser(_dictionary: user as! NSDictionary).saveUserToFireStore()
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to revert back to not using cached data